# 'PostFormView' object has no attribute 'method'

Tags: python, django

Я новичок и уже долгое время не могу справится с такого рода ошибками.
Вот мой код.
Urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from new_blog.views import RegisterView, LoginView, ProfileView, PostFormView
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name = 'post_list'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/', views.post_detail, name = 'post_detail'),
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name = 'register'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name = 'login'),
    path('profile/', ProfileView.as_view(), name = 'profile'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name = 'logout'),
    path('create/', PostFormView.as_view(), name = 'post_create' ),]`
```

views

```
class PostFormView(forms.ModelForm, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'new_blog/post_form.html'
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields =('title', 'slug', 'description', 'body')
    def post(request, self):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post = Post()
            post.title = request.POST.get('title')
            post.slug = request.POST.get('slug')
            post.description = request.POST.get('description')
            post.body = request.POST.get('body')
            post.author = (User.username)
            post.publish = datetime.datetime.now()
            post.status = 'published'
            post.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Python слово-указатель `self` в методах класса всегда ставится на первое место в списке параметров метода. Если я правильно понял проблему, то поменяйте код:

```
def post(request, self):
```

замените на

```
def post(self, request):
```

Comment: Проблема решена!!! Столько всего попробовал, перешел от классового представления к обычному , но ничего не помогало... Оказывается, я как минимум в шаблоне создания поста вместо name = 'title', указал name = 'tiLtle'